# Can we store a file as secret in bitbucket, where all the secret variables could be defined?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

As per what's mentioned in the doc -

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/

There is no way mentioned to store all the secret variables in a single file and then expose that file altogether to the pipeline.

Defining each variable as a separate secrets means we need to update the pipeline script every time a new variable is added. However, if there were a file to hold all the secrets and dynamically expose all those secret variables, we won't need to update the script every time a new variable is added.

FWIW, this is similar to to what is followed in case of Flutter -

Individually defining each variable -

```
--dart-define=someVariable=someValue --dart-define=otherVariable=otherValue --dart-define=thirdVariable=thirdValue
```

VS

Defining them all in one file -

```
--dart-define-from-file=<use-define-config.json>
```

So, is there a way to achieve the similar thing (to dart-define-from-file) in bitbucket secrets ?

Answer (score 1):

**Security disclaimer:** The approach described in this answer effectively defeats a Bitbucket Pipelines security feature that would prevent the accidental exposure of a secret if it was ever printed in the pipeline logs.

---

You can store a whole dotfile as your secret variable and then just export its contents or dump the content to a file where certain tooling could load it.

But note that

1. You will loose a security feature that would prevent exposing individual secrets accidentally printed in the CI logs
2. You may need to encode the file with base64 to keep linebreaks, see [How to store a file as bitbucket pipeline variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73935685/11715259)

Also, all your steps should be prefaced by either

```yaml
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &export-secrets >-
        export $(echo $SECRETS | base64 --decode)

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: 
          - *export-secrets
          - # ...
```

or

```yaml
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &dump-secrets >-
        echo $SECRETS | base64 --decode > .env

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: 
          - *dump-secrets
          - # ...
```

Not really worth it IMHO but you do you.