# Ssh key stored in bitbucket variable has invalid format

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to build a Dockerfile in a Bitbucket pipeline. The Dockerfile does the following:

```
ARG SSH_KEY
RUN echo "${SSH_KEY}" > /home/.ssh/ssh_key
RUN chmod 400 /home/.ssh/ssh_key && eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /home/.ssh/ssh_key
```

The key is stored in my linux machine, and if I do

```
export SSH_KEY=$(cat path_to_ssh_key)
docker build --build-arg SSH_KEY="${SSH_KEY}"
```

everything works.

However, in the bitbucket pipeline it does not work. I have the ssh key stored in a bitbucket variable called `SSH_KEY` as well. To insert the key in the bitbucket variable I tried both simple copy-paste from my file as well as `cat ssh_key | xclip -selection clipboard`. The pipeline command is

```
script:
          - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
          - docker build --build-arg SSH_KEY="${SSH_KEY}" .
```

The pipeline fails with `Error loading key`, because of `invalid format`.

My hypothesis is that somehow the key format is corrupted when passing the bitbucket variable to `docker build`, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Do you see the key in `/home/.ssh/ssh_key`? Do you see the key in pipeline in `echo $"{SSH_KEY}"`? Etc. Debug it, one step at a time. What is the output of `cat -v` of the file? `hexdump -C`? Are there special characters, like dos line endings?

Comment: The path you're describing publishes your private key by including it in the image.  It'll be accessible via `docker history` and it can be `docker cp`'d out of the image.  Do the newer answers to [Clone private git repo with dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile) help you?  Can you avoid needing this ssh key entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the line breaks in your ssh key are being mangled and you need to encode it: see [How to store a file as bitbucket pipeline variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73935685/11715259)

---

Side notes:

- Copying a ssh key or any secret in a docker image is a quite bad practice because it will be leaked in the docker layers even if you later remove it. Instead, you should use an ssh mount if you need the ssh at build time. If you will need it at runtime, you'd better remove all that from your Dockerfile. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypessh
- Each docker `RUN` directive runs in an independent isolated shell environment. Any ssh-agent you started will immediately terminate and be unavailable to further instructions. Unless you are not showing many things from your Dockerfile, all what you showed is futile.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I will need the ssh key at runtime because we are still in the development stage and people that will use the service I am packaging in the docker image might want to checkout a different branch of it to experiment or other reasons. So the ability to open the docker image, checkout a different branch or pull a commit is a requirement in my case. But my understanding is that RUN --mount=type=ssh only works at build time, and since the ssh credentials won't be injected, no one will be able to check out a different branch

Comment: Then all that people should be given read rights on the repository so they can do that with their own ssh keys. Otherwise you might just share them that master ssh key instead, which they could now extract from the docker image anyway. At least you wouldn't have that secret leaked in every docker image you build.