# SSH connection failing on bitbucket pipeline, but working on local computer

Tags: ssh, alpine-linux, bitbucket-pipelines

When on my local computer, I can ssh into my server without using a password just fine by doing

```bash
ssh user1@example.com
```

Now when I check `/var/log/auth.log` on the server to see what ssh key was used, I get something like so

```
Feb 27 09:11:24 example sshd[1172697]: Accepted publickey for user1 from 146.70.115.169 port 36138 ssh2: RSA SHA256:Gf9ol8izys7sHnypV3jiLD4ftgjlknedb6zVi1EhYeY
Feb 27 09:11:24 example sshd[1172697]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user1 (uid=1000) by (uid=0)
```

Then I run the following command on my local to find the ssh key file that used

```bash
find ~/.ssh -iname "*.pub" -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {}  bash -c "readlink -f {}; ssh-keygen -l -f {}"
```

Once I get the file I encode it like so

```bash
base64 -w 0 < ~/.ssh/id_rsa > my_ssh_key
```

Once I get the encoded key, I save it as repository variable in bitbucket

I then created a script that runs on my bitbucket pipeline to deploy my project

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` looks something like this

```yaml
image: php:8.1.13-alpine3.15

pipelines:

  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging
          caches:
            - composer
            - npm
          script:
            - apk update && apk add --no-cache bash
            - bash deploy.sh
```

And the deploy script is like this

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ueo

echo "Build and deploy scripts"
apk update
apk add --no-cache openssh
apk add --update coreutils
echo "Deploy to test server"
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cat known_hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
(umask  077 ; echo "${SSH_KEY}" | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh -vvv "${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}" "echo 'Connection successful'"
echo "Ready for testing!"
```

The problem is my ssh connection on the pipeline is failing some reason

The debug output is like so

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: resolving "example.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup example.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to example.com [192.53.122.20] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to example.com:22 as 'user1'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from example.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/CCdDqCWoAUEk/MGUCv3mx3nDiHsEDBLjrk8R7nGpE4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from example.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'example.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:lW4tY23d2DGaxm6ypcBJTjYj6pFI66cAReRBinDDhBo
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:lW4tY23d2DGaxm6ypcBJTjYj6pFI66cAReRBinDDhBo
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Could somebody please help me figure out the issue?

Thank you

Comment: The `debug1: Will attempt key: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa  explicit` log line sounds like some config is preferring that file as if the `-I` CLI option had been passed instead of letting ssh discover the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` you dumped. I'd try to debug that

Comment: Any concern against using the private key that you can setup from the web UI? Just authorize that key in the server! Otherwise you are effectively exposing your individual private key even if you thought it was a secret --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/72057661/11715259

Comment: @N1ngu Do you think me [forcing the use of a specific key](https://superuser.com/questions/772660/howto-force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-private-key) would work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tips from @N1ngu and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/772660/howto-force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-private-key), I managed to solve the issue by changing my `ssh` command to

```bash
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa "${SSH_CS_USER}@${SSH_CS_HOST}" "echo 'Connected successfully'"
```